# ListView c TextBlock и Button

Tags: c#, listview, xaml, uwp

Я создаю на основе шаблона список, в котором текст и `Button`. `Button` по умолчанию скрыт. Осталась одна проблема: Как сделать так, чтобы `Button` появлялся только в той строке, на которой висит фокус (On Focused Item). Как мне привязать свойство `Button.Visibility = Visible` только к элементу, получившему фокус, а на остальных оно должно быть `Collapsed`. Вот код:

```
<ListView x:Name="FileList" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="FileList_SelectionChanged" Foreground="#FF00FFE8" IsItemClickEnabled="True"  Grid.Row="3" IsDoubleTapEnabled="False" IsRightTapEnabled="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="{Binding ElementName=FileList, Path=ActualWidth}">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="300*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Height="30" Width="300" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0"/>

                <Button Click="PlayButton_Click" Content="Play" Height="30" Width="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: можно с помощью триггеров. Посмотрите Interactivity:EventTrigger пример. Там должно быть просто

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего, вероятно, так:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="<что у вас там>"
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="B2V"/>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="300*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock
                    Text="{Binding}" Height="30" Width="300" Grid.Column="0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                <Button
                    Content="Play" Height="30" Width="50" Grid.Column="2"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Visibility="{Binding IsKeyboardFocusWithin, RelativeSource=
                                    {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListViewItem},
                                  Converter={StaticResource B2V}}">
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

(Чтобы заставить Item растянуться на всю ширину, нужен не Binding/стиль, а `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` на самом `ListView`.)

Comment: На uwp ivent trigger не работает вроде. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @Morgomirius: Пожалуйста. Рад, если помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Можно при событии фокуса показывать кнопку с помощью VisualStates в шаблоне айтема.